# HTML 5 Upload files using drag and drop

Tags: ajax, file-upload, xmlhttprequest, session-variables, laravel-5.4

I would like to upload files using a drag and drop

I'm using laravel framework 5.4 and JS. The problem is with what happens after the upload is complete. I can see the file is uploaded to the folder but can't get the name of the file or any reference to it.

This is my view.. I'm uploading files to send as email attachments

```
 {!! Form::open([
    'url' => 'send',
    'files' => true,
    'id'=>'upload',
    'enctype'=> 'multipart/form-data'
]) !!}
  <div class="box-body">
    <div class="form-group">
      {!! Form::text('to', null, ['class' => 'form-control', 'placeholder' => 'Send to']) !!}
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      {!! Form::text('subject', null, ['class' => 'form-control', 'placeholder' => 'Subject']) !!}
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      {!! Form::textarea('content', null, ['class' => 'form-control message-body wysihtml5-sandbox', 'placeholder' => 'Message']) !!}
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="hidden" id="MAX_FILE_SIZE" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="320000" />
        <div>
            <label for="fileselect">Files to upload:</label>
            <input type="file" id="fileselect" name="fileselect[]" multiple="multiple" />
           <div id="filedrag">or drop files here</div>
        </div>
        <div id="progress"></div>
        <div id="messages">
        </div>
  </div><!-- /.box-body -->
  <div class="box-footer">
    <div class="pull-right">
      {{--<button class="btn btn-default"><i class="fa fa-pencil"></i> Draft</button>--}}
        {!! Form::submit('Send', ['class' => 'btn btn-primary submit']) !!}
                    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="hidden" id="MAX_FILE_SIZE" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="320000" />
        <div>
            <label for="fileselect">Files to upload:</label>
            <input type="file" id="fileselect" name="fileselect[]" multiple="multiple" />
            <div id="filedrag">or drop files here</div>
        </div>
        <div id="progress"></div>
        <div id="messages">
        </div>
  </div><!-- /.box-body -->
  <div class="box-footer">
        {!! Form::submit('Send', ['class' => 'btn btn-primary submit']) !!}
```

The scripts I'm using

```
(function() {

    var send = XMLHttpRequest.prototype.send,
        token = $('meta[name=csrf-token]').attr('content');
    XMLHttpRequest.prototype.send = function(data) {
        this.setRequestHeader('X-CSRF-Token', token);
        return send.apply(this, arguments);
    }


    // getElementById
    function $id(id) {
        return document.getElementById(id);
    }
    // output information
    function Output(msg) {
        var m = $id("messages");
        m.innerHTML = msg + m.innerHTML;
    }
    // file drag hover
    function FileDragHover(e) {
        e.stopPropagation();
        e.preventDefault();
        e.target.className = (e.type == "dragover" ? "hover" : "");
    }
    // file selection
    function FileSelectHandler(e) {

        // cancel event and hover styling
        FileDragHover(e);

        // fetch FileList object
        var files = e.target.files || e.dataTransfer.files;

        // process all File objects
        for (var i = 0, f; f = files[i]; i++) {
            UploadFile(f);
        }

    }

    function UploadFile(file) {

        // following line is not necessary: prevents running on SitePoint servers

        var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

        if (xhr.upload && file.size <= $id("MAX_FILE_SIZE").value) {

            // create progress bar
            var o = $id("progress");
            var progress = o.appendChild(document.createElement("p"));
            progress.appendChild(document.createTextNode("upload " + file.name));


            // progress bar
            xhr.upload.addEventListener("progress", function (e) {
                var pc = parseInt(100 - (e.loaded / e.total * 100));
                progress.style.backgroundPosition = pc + "% 0";
            }, false);

            // file received/failed
            xhr.onreadystatechange = function (e) {
                if (xhr.readyState == 4) {
                    progress.className = (xhr.status == 200 ? "success" : "failure");
                }
            };

            // start upload
            xhr.open("POST", '/getAttachments', true);
            xhr.setRequestHeader("X_FILENAME", file.name);
            xhr.send(file);
        }
    }

    // initialize
    function Init() {

        var fileselect = $id("fileselect"),
            filedrag = $id("filedrag"),
            submitbutton = $id("submitbutton");

        // file select
        fileselect.addEventListener("change", FileSelectHandler, false);

        // is XHR2 available?
        var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        if (xhr.upload) {

            // file drop
            filedrag.addEventListener("dragover", FileDragHover, false);
            filedrag.addEventListener("dragleave", FileDragHover, false);
            filedrag.addEventListener("drop", FileSelectHandler, false);
            filedrag.style.display = "block";

        }

    }

    // call initialization file
    if (window.File && window.FileList && window.FileReader) {
        Init();
    }
})();
```

The script I used was using the form action attribute to upload the files. Since the form action is to send the email, I routed xhr.open("POST", '/getAttachments', true) to a different controller method that I call in the send method.

My controller methods @getAttachments and @send

```
public function getAttachments()
if ($fn) {
// AJAX call
file_put_contents(
    'uploads/' . $fn,
    file_get_contents('php://input')
);
 return $fn ; // HERE $fn = false though the name of the file stored is correct
 }}
```

and I tried

```
Storage::put($fn, file_get_contents('php://input'));
$file = Storage::get($fn) ; return $file;);

public function send( Request $request ) {
$file = $this->getAttachments();
// $file = $false}
```

I figured it is returning false because if I hit send the page refreshes 
 and $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FILENAME'] variable is lost, so I tried saving it to the session but no use.. Can't get the files

```
public function getAttachments()
{
    $fn = (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FILENAME']) ? $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FILENAME'] : false);
    if ($fn) {
        session(['attachments' => $fn]);
        Storage::put($fn, file_get_contents('php://input'));
    }
}
public function send( Request $request ) {
        //Grab uploaded file
    if ($request->session()->exists('attachments')) {
       $attachments = $request->session()->pull('attachments');
        $files = Storage::get($attachments);
    }
```

Don't know why but it doesn't store to the session either.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what exactly you are trying to do. But if you to want to upload a file by drag and drop then I would suggest you use this awesome js:

http://www.dropzonejs.com/

If you would like to see the implementation, then you can check it over here:

https://github.com/xparthx/Laravel-AWS-S3

Comment: I can't get dropzone to upload any files. It works on the front but I tried it once before trying the HTML5 upload and now when you suggested it, and I can't find the file in the folder specified. Will take a closer look at its options but for now I'm trying to go with this. And this is the tutorial I followed if it will help you understand better  http://www.sitepoint.com/html5-ajax-file-upload